# What are the steps to create multiple schema in Solr4.x with zookeeper

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I have a requirement like :-
I have to create multiple schema and perform a join on them. Now I want to do this on Solr Cloud with zookeeper, the problem here is I have uploaded conf directory to zookeeper and I need to have multiple collection, but I don't know how to change schema.xml for this.

Kindly guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload multiple configuration to zookeeper and name them differently.
Then while creating your collection specify the appropriate config name

For e.g.
java -classpath .:/solr-test/deployment/solr-war/lib/* org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkCLI -cmd upconfig -zkhost localhost:2181,localhost:2181,localhost:2181 -confdir /home/mdhussain/Data/sabahcdm/solr-test/deployment/solr-war/config1 -confname solrConfig1

java -classpath .:/solr-test/deployment/solr-war/lib/* org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkCLI -cmd upconfig -zkhost localhost:2181,localhost:2181,localhost:2181 -confdir /home/mdhussain/Data/sabahcdm/solr-test/deployment/solr-war/config2 -confname solrConfig2

curl `http://127.0.0.1:6080/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=collection1&numShards=1&replicationFactor=1&collection.configName=solrConfig1`

curl `http://127.0.0.1:6080/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=collection2&numShards=1&replicationFactor=1&collection.configName=solrConfig2`

Thanks
-Hussain